# Changing name after refactoring an activity does not work

Tags: android-activity, refactoring

I have an intent

```
Intent(context, VisualCActivity::class.java).putExtra("Pox", BLBIndex)
```

thats works before.

Then I refactor the activity to another name and it works again ???

but the old name in the intent stays the same

But when I change the name of the activity in the intent to the new name

it does not work (unresolved reference)

What can I do?

Edit: I found the old activity name in the manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".VisualCActivity"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_visual_cactivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LKPRG2023" />
```

Can I rename it here?

Android Studio shows in project window the new name

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake

class declaration name hasn't change - now it works

```
class FRMain : ComponentActivity() {
```